# Stack buffer class

Tags: c++, c++11

This is a class for storing memory on the stack when possible or in `std::vector` when it grows too much.

**Note:** Using `std::vector` with custom stack allocator would be arguably better but I did not want to depend on 3<sup>rd</sup> party allocators (and could not find one for C++11 that compiles cleanly).

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

template<std::size_t STACK_SIZE = 128>
class stack_buf
{    
public:
    using bufpair_t = std::pair<const char*, std::size_t>;
    stack_buf() :_v(), _stack_array(), _stack_size(0) {}
    ~stack_buf() {};

    stack_buf& operator=(const stack_buf& other) = delete;

    stack_buf(const stack_buf& other)
    {
        _stack_size = other._stack_size;
        if (!other._v.empty())
            _v = other._v;
        else if (_stack_size)
            std::copy(other._stack_array.begin(), other._stack_array.begin() + _stack_size, _stack_array.begin());
    }

    stack_buf(stack_buf&& other)
    {
        _stack_size = other._stack_size;
        if (!other._v.empty())
            _v = std::move(other._v);
        else if (_stack_size)
            std::copy(other._stack_array.begin(), other._stack_array.begin() + _stack_size, _stack_array.begin());
        other.clear();
    }

    void append(const char* buf, std::size_t buf_size)
    {
        //If we are aleady using _v, forget about the stack
        if (!_v.empty())
        {
            _v.insert(_v.end(), buf, buf + buf_size);
        }
        //Try use the stack
        else
        {
            if (_stack_size + buf_size <= STACK_SIZE)
            {
                std::memcpy(&_stack_array[_stack_size], buf, buf_size);
                _stack_size += buf_size;
            }
            //Not enough stack space. Copy all to _v
            else
            {
                _v.reserve(_stack_size + buf_size);
                if (_stack_size)
                    _v.insert(_v.end(), _stack_array.begin(), _stack_array.begin() + _stack_size);
                _v.insert(_v.end(), buf, buf + buf_size);
            }
        }
    }

    void append(const bufpair_t &buf)
    {
        append(buf.first, buf.second);
    }

    void clear()
    {
        _stack_size = 0;
        _v.clear();
    }

    bufpair_t get() const
    {
        if (!_v.empty())
            return bufpair_t(_v.data(), _v.size());
        else
            return bufpair_t(_stack_array.data(), _stack_size);
    }

    std::size_t size() const
    {
        if (!_v.empty())
            return _v.size();
        else
            return _stack_size;
    }

private:
    std::vector<char> _v;
    std::array<char, STACK_SIZE> _stack_array;
    std::size_t _stack_size;
};
```

Comment: [Leading underscores are reserved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: @Jamal A leading underscore followed by a capital letter and double underscores are "reserved". In the global namespace, leading underscores are "reserved"

Comment: @GamiMe Looks like a small string optimization. Why don't you just use the `std::string` of your Standard Library implementation?

Comment: @dyp. SSO is implementation dependent and won't give me the option to choose stack size as far as I know

Comment: Why is the assignment-operator deleted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 1. Leading underscores

As Jamal pointed out in the comments, using a leading `_` is dangerous, since it easily uses a reserved identifier (for example, when followed by a capital letter). I think the leading underscores are not a problem here, but I'd advise against using them. Some people use trailing underscores for data members for this reason.

#### 2. Includes

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cstddef> // or <cstring>; for std::size_t
#include <vector>
```

I sorted them alphabetically (thanks, Morwenn) so you can see if you include them multiple times.

#### 3. Template parameters

```
template<typename T = char, std::size_t N = 50>
class stack_buf
```

I don't see any reason why should constrain this class to `char`. It works perfectly fine for other types, and doesn't use any string assumptions/functionality.

#### 4. Publishing information

```
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using iterator = T const*;
    using bufpair_t = std::pair<iterator, std::size_t>;
    static constexpr std::size_t stack_size = N;
```

I think it's typically a good idea to publish the information about the type of your class, since you can infer this via partial specialization anyway. The `iterator` typedef increases compatibility with StdLib container classes.

#### 5. Reducing code duplication

The copy constructor and move constructor are almost equivalent. With some function templates, we can reduce the code duplication:

```
private:
    struct delegate_copy_move{};
    template<class T1>
    stack_buf(T1&& other, delegate_copy_move)
        : _stack_size( other._stack_size )
    {
        if (other.uses_vector())
            _v = std::forward<T1>(other)._v;
        else
            std::copy_n(other._stack_array.begin(), _stack_size, _stack_array.begin());
    }

    bool uses_vector() const
    {
        return ! _v.empty();
    }

public:
    stack_buf(stack_buf const& other)
        : stack_buf(other, delegate_copy_move{})
    {}

    stack_buf(stack_buf&& other)
        : stack_buf(std::move(other), delegate_copy_move{})
    {
        other.clear();
    }
```

Note that I also replaced `std::copy` with `std::copy_n`, and removed the redundant check `if (_stack_size)`: both algorithms work correctly with empty ranges. For arbitrary types, we should replace the `copy_n` with a `move`, dependent on whether `T1` is an lvalue ref (something like a `forward_n`).

The `uses_vector()` helper function IMO increases readability, and becomes more important in an optimization (see below).

#### 6. Default constructor and destructor

```
    stack_buf() : _stack_size(0) {}
    ~stack_buf() = default;
```

I'd advise against explicitly initializing the `_stack_array` data member. This will perform value-initialization, which zeroes the array. The user of the class then doesn't have any way to create an uninitialized `stack_buf`. However, by leaving out the value-init, the user still can write `stack_buf<> s{};` or `auto s = stack_buf<>{};` for value-initialization.

The destructor should be defaulted or left out completely.

#### 7. The `append` function

```
    void append(value_type const* buf, std::size_t buf_size)
    {
        if (uses_vector())
        {
            _v.insert(_v.end(), buf, buf + buf_size);
        }
        else
        {
            if (_stack_size + buf_size <= stack_size)
            {
                std::copy_n(buf, buf_size, _stack_array.begin() + _stack_size);
                _stack_size += buf_size;
            }
            //Not enough stack space. Copy all to _v
            else
            {
                _v.reserve(_stack_size + buf_size);
                try
                {
                    _v.insert(_v.end(), _stack_array.begin(),
                              _stack_array.begin() + _stack_size);
                    _v.insert(_v.end(), buf, buf + buf_size);
                }catch(...)
                {
                    _v.clear();
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I replaced the `std::memcpy` with a `std::copy_n`. As far as I know, there's no reason to use use `std::memcpy` at all. Again, I removed the redundant check `if(_stack_size)`.

With the try-catch-clause, the `append` function now doesn't "lose" any data: When an exception occurs, we still have the data in the stack array, but the user cannot access it. By clearing the vector, we restore access to this data.

Instead of the try-catch-clause, you could also introduce a temporary vector (see below).

For arbitrary element types, we should probably use `move_if_noexcept` to move the elements from the array to the vector. If this is successful, we should destroy the elements in the stack array (since they might have been copied). This requires replacing the `copy_n` with some placement-new calls.

#### 8. Accessors

```
    bufpair_t get() const
    {
        if (uses_vector())
            return bufpair_t(_v.data(), _v.size());
        else
            return bufpair_t(_stack_array.data(), _stack_size);
    }
    iterator begin() const
    {
        return get().first;
    }
    iterator end() const
    {
        return get().first + get().second;
    }

    std::size_t size() const
    {
        return get().second;
    }
```

I added the usual `begin` and `end` accessors so your `stack_buf` can be used in range-based for loops etc. All of them, including `size`, now rely on `get`, which is intended to reduce code duplication.

---

#### On the data structure itself

It is not optimal: it uses too much stack space. A first optimization is to share the space between the vector and the array, and to reduce the size of the `_stack_size` member. This saves you up to 31 byte on a 64-bit machine (a vector is typically 3 pointers in size, and `_stack_size` doesn't need to be greater than a byte typically).

This is still not optimal, as we do not use 7 of the 8 bits of `_stack_size` when the `vector` is active.

Here are the basic ideas:

```
template<typename T = char, std::size_t N = 128, typename S = std::size_t>
class stack_buf
{
public:
    using stack_size_t = S;
    static constexpr stack_capacity = N;

    static_assert(   stack_capacity < std::numeric_limits<stack_size_t>::max()
                  || (   stack_capacity == std::numeric_limits<stack_size_t>::max()
                      && std::is_signed<stack_size_t>())
                  , "The stack size type is too small.");
```

Let the user determine what type is used as the stack size type, or just use a `uint8_t` or `unsigned char`.

```
bool uses_vector() const
{
    return static_cast<stack_size_t>(-1) == _stack_size;
}
```

Use a single bit to store the information whether the stack or the array is in use.

```
union
{
    vector_t _v;
    array_t _stack_array;
};
stack_size_t _stack_size;
```

Combine the vector and the array.

```
template<class T1>
stack_buf(T1&& other, delegate_copy_move)
    : _stack_size( other._stack_size )
{
    if (other.uses_vector())
        new ((void*)&_v) vector_t( std::forward<T1>(other)._v );
    else
    {
        new ((void*)&_stack_array) array_t;
        std::copy_n(other._stack_array.begin(), _stack_size, _stack_array.begin());
    }
}
```

Use placement-new to construct the vector or array.

`append` is a bit tricky, since you cannot just copy from the array to the vector (they share the same memory). However, moving a vector is cheap:

```
void append(value_type const* buf, std::size_t buf_size)
{
    if (uses_vector())
    {
        _v.insert(_v.end(), buf, buf + buf_size);
    }
    else
    {
        if (_stack_size + buf_size <= stack_size)
        {
            std::copy_n(_buf, buf_size, _stack_array+_stack_size);
            _stack_size += buf_size;
        }
        //Not enough stack space. Copy all to _v
        else
        {
            vector_t tmp;
            tmp.reserve(_stack_size + buf_size);
            tmp.insert(tmp.end(), _stack_array.begin(),
                       _stack_array.begin() + _stack_size);
            tmp.insert(tmp.end(), buf, buf + buf_size);

            _stack_array.~array_t();
            new ((void*)&_v) vector_t( std::move(tmp) );
            _stack_size = static_cast<stack_size_t>(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also replace the try-catch-clause with the technique used in the optimization (construct another vector and move after construction).

Comment: About the static cast to -1:wouldn't that introduce a bug if the _stack_size==maxval?  uses_vector() would return true

Comment: @GabiMe True, I've inserted a `static_assert` to cover that case, but failed to copy it into my answer.

Comment: Another question: Does _v = std::forward<T1>(other)._v ensures that _v get moved if T1 is rvalue?

Comment: rvalue/lvalue is a category of an expression, so `T1` being a type cannot be an rvalue/lvalue. However, this function template uses a technique known as *perfect forwarding*, which achieves what I think you wanted to say: `forward<T1>(other)` converts `other` to an rvalue if the argument expression from which `T1` has been deduced is an rvalue. If it is an rvalue, `forward<T1>(other)._v` is an rvalue as well, which allows moving from `other._v`.